# How to call a java main function?

Tags: java, input, program-entry-point

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Calculator operand1 operator operand2");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int result = 0;
        switch (args[1].charAt(0)) {
        case '+':
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            break;
        case '*':
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            break;
        case '/':
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(args[0] + ' ' + args[1] + ' ' + args[2] + " = " + result);
    }
}
```

When I ran `Calculator.java` in terminal, I tried a few ways like this:

```
Rasperry:src maggiesmac$ javac Calculator.java
Rasperry:src maggiesmac$ java Calculator 1+2
Usage: java Calculator operand1 operator operand2
Rasperry:src maggiesmac$ java Calculator 1 + 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:572)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:15)
Rasperry:src maggiesmac$ java Calculator.main(1,+,2)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So how can I call the Java `main()` method? How should I pass the parameters to it?

Comment: What do you think `Integer.parseInt(args[1]` does with the command line arguments `1 + 2`? What do you think the exception is trying  to  tell you?

Comment: You did call the main function. If you actually read the output, you can see that there is a syntax error.

Comment: Your main function is being called, that's not the problem. Look at the error message. You're trying to parse something into an integer, that clearly is not an integer.

Comment: Voting to close as typo, wrong index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the index in the case structure (as suggested by @SotiriosDelimanolis). Also, we can use String in case:

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Calculator operand1 operator operand2");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int result = 0;
        switch (args[1]) {
        case "+":
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        case "-":
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        case "*":
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        case "/":
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(args[0] + ' ' + args[1] + ' ' + args[2] + " = " + result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below the code get the result

```
class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Calculator operand1 operator operand2");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int result = 0;
    char op = args[1].charAt(0);
    System.out.println((int)op);

    int ope = (int)op;

        switch (ope) {
        case 43:
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        case 45:
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) - Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        case 42:
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) * Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        case 47:
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[0]) / Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(args[0] + ' ' + args[1] + ' ' + args[2] + " = " + result);
    }
}
```